# How to take input of a sentence where each word is in a string array, untill user presses enter

Tags: c++, string, cin

I have to input a sentence for example:- The cat ate mouse. The each word of the sentence shouls be stored in an array of string s[]. Thus, s[0]=The, s[1]=cat s2=ate and so on. The input of words should be taken until user presses enter.

I have tried multiple methods, most of them work on my machine (using terminal) for n test cases but it shows a runtime error in online judges like CodeChef.

```
/*
Below is the method I tried. Test case showing RUNTIME ERROR is:-
3   (No of test cases)        
vbc def ghij alpha
This will test your coding skills
Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers
*/
```

Original problem was to sort the words of the sentence in lexical order.

```
while(ch!='\n')
                {
                        cin>>s[i];
                        i++;
                        scanf("%c", &ch);
                        //cout<<"hi"<<endl;
                        if(ch=='\n')
                                break;
                }
```

I have checked that my sorting algorithm works fine, the problem is with input.
After 2nd sentence code generates Infinite no of HI's did as debugging statement, Implying while loop runs infinitely there.

```
/*Output was:-
 hi
 hi
 hi
 hi
 alpha ghij def vbc 
 hi
 hi
 hi
 hi
 hi
 hi
 skills coding your test will This 
 hi
 hi
 hi
 hi
 hi
 hi..... Infinitely*/
```

Comment: You can use std::getline and then std::istringstream.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Thank you very much, however, I am not able to implement it if you could write an outline of the loop that will be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could separate the input string using a simple loop like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
 string S;
 string strings[5]; // whatever the size
 unsigned index = 0;

 getline(cin, S);
 for (unsigned i = 0; i < S.size(); i++)
 {
    if (S[i] == ' ')
        index++;
    else
        strings[index] += S[i];
 }

 for (unsigned i = 0; i < 5; i++)  // whatever the size again
    cout << strings[i] << endl;
}
```

Input:

```
I like big yellow birds
```

Output:

```
I
like
big
yellow
birds
```

Comment: Why is it known that there are exactly five words?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow it's not, I just put five as an example, he can put any size he wants or even make the size dynamic, I just didn't want to complicate the code.
my main focus was on separating the string into a bunch of smaller strings